# Xamarin.iOS GPUImage : How can i create GPUImageTwoInputFilter with custom shader file in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to create a GPUImageTwoInputFilter with custom shader file in xamarin.iOS. I am using GPUImage component.

```
var stillCamera = new GPUImageStillCamera ();
var filter1 = new GPUImageTwoInputFilter();
stillCamera.AddTarget(filter1);
var internalSourcePicture1 = new GPUImagePicture(UIImage.FromFile("image.png").CGImage,true);
internalSourcePicture1.AddTarget(filter1);
internalSourcePicture1.ProcessImage();
```

but don't know how do we pass shader file in GPUImageTwoInputFilter

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom fragment shader (`.fsh`) to your `Xamarin.iOS` app bundle as a build type of `BundleResource`.

Then load it via `GPUImageFilter.FromFragmentShaderFile`:

**Note: Do not include the *file extension* or you will get a "Failed to load vertex shader" in the app output/log**

```
var filter = GPUImageFilter.FromFragmentShaderFile ("StackOverflowShader");
```

or embed the fragment shader as a string:

```
    fragShaderString = @"
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2;

 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;

 void main()
 {
    lowp vec4 base = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    lowp vec4 overlayer = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(min(overlayer.rgb * base.a, base.rgb * overlayer.a) + overlayer.rgb * (1.0 - base.a) + base.rgb * (1.0 - overlayer.a), 1.0);
 }

";
```

And load it via `FromFragmentShaderString`:

```
var filter = GPUImageFilter.FromFragmentShaderString(fragShaderString);
```

Comment: how we will apply a source picture because after add source picture it's throws an exception "Failed to load vertex shader" on this line "internalSourcePicture1.AddTarget(filter1);" and there is no effect on camera screen after apply custom shader.

Comment: @R.Gupta GPUImageFilter (with a **Fragment Shader**) ->  GPUImageTwoInputFilter -> YourXXXXXFilter : You might want to look at how they are done in ObjC to understand, then you can use the `initWithFragmentShaderFromString:` selector to construct one  https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/54d69e04080860d7da2d3b62c1f5de4259e51d36/framework/Source/GPUImageDarkenBlendFilter.m and Xamarin ObjC selectors : http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/objective-c_selectors/

Comment: I am trying to apply GPUImageDarkenBlendFilter but it's showing a white screen

Comment: Created new library of GUImage for Xamarin.iOS